# Ajax spinners for angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to show ajax spinners on one of angularJS application with every http call, so it means whenever we try to load a ngGrid or Dropdown etc there will be a spinner on place and when loading get complete it will get removed, I am new on angular not sure how can we achieve it, please give any reference.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this loading bar: http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-loading-bar/
You can take som inspiration from there of how to implement your own spinner.

Comment: Thanks Your help is really very help full Anton ...

Answer (score 1):

Try using an ngSwitch, where you will swap two templates, so basically it would be something like this:

```
<div ng-switch on="loaded">
  <div ng-switch-when="true">
      <!--your loaded content goes here-->
  </div>
  <div ng-switch-default>
      <!--your spinner goes here-->
  </div>
</div>
```

That way in your controller you can do something like:

```
$scope.loadSomething = function(){
    $scope.loaded = false;
    $http.get(url).success(function(data){
        $scope.loaded = true;
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write some plain old JavaScript to add a class name to the DIV or TABLE before the call to `$http.foo`, and then in a success/failure callback remove that class name.

CSS:

```
.loading {
    background: transparent url(path/to/loading.gif) no-repeat scroll 50% 50%;
}

.loading * {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```